# Python: Split a list into smaller jsons based on another list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have one list of program names which need to be sorted into lists of smaller jsons based of a priority list. I need to do this in python 3.
B and C being of the same priority 2, they will be in a list together.

```
program_names = ['A','B','C','D']
priorities = [1,2,2,3]
```

Required end result:

```
[[{"name": "A"}], [{"name":"B"}, {"name":"C"}], [{"name":"D"}]]
```

Current code:

```
program_names_list = []
    final_list = []
    for x in program_names.split(','):
        program_names_list.append(x)
    for x in program_names_list:
        final_list.append([{"name": x}])
```

That's what I currently have which is outputting the following result:

```
[[{'name': 'A'}], [{'name': 'B'}], [{'name': 'C'}], [{'name': 'D'}]]
```

I should add that program_names is a string "A,B,C,D"

Comment: What have you done so far? This is not a code writing service you know where you will tell the requirements and someone would whip out code for you

Comment: @NSNoob - added my current code - see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Full solution

```
items = {}
for k, v in zip(priorities, program_names):
    items.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
[[{'name': name} for name in items[key]] for key in sorted(items.keys())]
```

returns:

```
[[{'name': 'A'}], [{'name': 'B'}, {'name': 'C'}], [{'name': 'D'}]]
```

### In steps

Create a dictionary that uses the priorities as keys and a list of all program names with corresponding priority as values:

```
items = {}
for k, v in zip(priorities, program_names):
    items.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Go through the sorted keys and create a new list of program names by getting them from the dictionary by the key:

```
[[{'name': name} for name in items[key]] for key in sorted(items.keys())]
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the priorities and use a dictionary with priorities as keys and lists of programs as values to group all elements with the same priority.

```
In [24]: from collections import defaultdict

In [25]: program_names = ['A','B','C','D']

In [26]: priorities = [1,2,2,3]

In [27]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [28]: for i, p in enumerate(sorted(priorities)):
    d[p].append({'name': program_names[i]})
   ....:

In [29]: list(d.values())
Out[29]: [[{'name': 'A'}], [{'name': 'B'}, {'name': 'C'}], [{'name': 'D'}]]
```

Comment: @user4659009 Just convert it to a list, I updated the answer. That happens because python3 does not return a list for dict.values.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may be wrong from an educational point of view, I cannot resist answering such questions by one-liners:

```
[[{'name': p_n} for p_i, p_n in zip(priorities, program_names) if p_i == p] for p in sorted(set(priorities))]
```

(This assumes your "priorities" list may be sorted and is less efficient than the "normal" approach with a `defaultdict(list)`).

**Update:** Borrowing from damn_c-s answer, here's an efficient one-liner (not counting the implied `from itertools import groupby`):

```
[[{'name': pn} for pi, pn in l] for v, l in groupby(zip(priorities, program_names), lambda x: x[0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby.

```
from itertools import groupby

program_names = ['a','b','c','d']
priorities = [1,2,2,3]

data = zip(priorities, program_names)

groups_dict = []
for k, g in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0]):
    m = map(lambda x: dict(name=x[1]), list(g))
    groups_dict.append(m)

print(groups_dict)
```